# how to give permission to specific folder in amazon ec2 server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, httpd

I updated my php version 5 to 7 in the aws ec2 server. After I have updated my root folder permission, it has been changed to `drwxr-sr-x` when I try to change permission I got error like

> chmod: changing permissions of ‘/mnt/my-data/webroot/’: Operation not permitted

And one more thing here I have used separate folder to access my website means that I am not using  `/var/www/html` instead of that I have created one more folder like `/mnt/my-data/webroot/`.

And after installation of php 7 I got one more error like

> AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf.d/virtual-hosts.conf:1

Here I have created virtual hosts and it is working fine. Now how to solve issue and how can I give `755` permission to `/mnt/my-data/webroot/` this folder and when ever try any chmod operation I got an error like

> chmod: changing permissions of ‘/mnt/my-data/webroot/’: Operation not permitted

How can I solve this?

Comment: can any one please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

To correct permissions, run the following commands on your EC2 instance:

```
 sudo chown root:root /home
 sudo chmod 755 /home
 sudo chown ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user -R
 sudo chmod 700 /home/ec2-user /home/ec2-user/.ssh
 sudo chmod 600 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

To correct permission for specific folder and all it's contents run this command, this is a very powerful command and please mind what you're giving permissions to!

```
sudo chmod ugo+rwx /home/ec2-user/specific-folder/.*
```